# javascriptで透過処理が動作しない

Tags: javascript

このプログラムのjavascriptが動いてないみたいで
透明化されないのですけどもどうしてでしょうか
おしえてくださいお願いしますm(__)m

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
    <title>サンプル 02</title>
    <script language="javascript">
var opacity = 50;

function document_load() {
    fore.style.filter = "Alpha(Opacity=" + opacity + ")";
    label.innerHTML = "Opacity=" + opacity;
}
function dec_click() {
    if (opacity > 0) opacity -= 10;
    fore.style.filter = "Alpha(Opacity=" + opacity + ")";
    label.innerHTML = "Opacity=" + opacity;
}
function inc_click() {
    if (opacity < 100) opacity += 10;
    fore.style.filter = "Alpha(Opacity=" + opacity + ")";
    label.innerHTML = "Opacity=" + opacity;
}
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="document_load()">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr><td align="center">
        <input type="button" onClick="dec_click()"
               value="より透明に">
        <input type="button" onClick="inc_click()"
               value="より不透明に">
    </th></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><p id="label">Opacity=100</td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center" style="
        background-image:url(back00.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
    ">
        <img src="fore00.jpg" id="fore">
    </th></tr></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: まず対象ブラウザとバージョンを質問に追加する必要があります。この[リンク](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_filter.asp) が参考になります。chrome ver.53 の場合 `fore.style.filter = "opacity(" + opacity + "%)";` で動作しました。

Comment: firefoxの49.0.1は利用できないということ・・・なのでしょうか？

Comment: firefox 47.0.1(windows) でも動作しましたので、先のコメントと同じ変更で(CSS3.0にちゃんと対応しているならば）大丈夫だと思います。(リンク先からだと35から対応ということらしいですね）

Comment: 一応ですが、`script`タグの`language`プロパティはかなり前から非推奨です。書くとすれば`type`の方ですが、最近ではjsがデフォルトなので大概いりません。あと`meta`タグも古い書き方のような気が。

Comment: @packet0 さん、書き方が古いも何もIE4（1997/09）～IE7（2006/10）の頃にIE専用に書かれたコードと思われます。IE8では`filter`の代わりに`-ms-filter`が導入されていますのでそれ以前。

Comment: @sayuri さん、やっぱりかなり古いですよね。どこから掘り出してきたんでしょう... というかこのころスクリプトにid直（`getElementById()`なし）で指定できたんですね...

Comment: @packet0  ID名で直接要素にアクセスできるのは確かIEの拡張だったと思います。 ChromeやFirefoxで利用できるのでビックリしましたが、[規格](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object)に取り込まれたようです。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY まさかの規格入り＆初耳です... これまともなサイト作ってる人で使う人いるんですかね。

Answer (score 1):

[対応表](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)を見てもらえば分かると思いますが、
確認するブラウザによっては動きません。
2つくらい透明化するスタイルを追加しました。
(IE10って普通に`opacity`効いたと思うので、後おまけで`moz-opacity`やっておく)

```js
var opacity = 50;

function document_load() {
    //透明化（既存）
    fore.style.filter = "Alpha(Opacity=" + opacity + ")";
    //透明化（追加）
    fore.style.opacity = (opacity*0.01);
    fore.style.MozOpacity = (opacity*0.01);
    label.innerHTML = "Opacity=" + opacity;
}
function dec_click() {
    if (opacity > 0) opacity -= 10;
    document_load();
}
function inc_click() {
    if (opacity < 100) opacity += 10;
    document_load();
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
    <title>サンプル 02</title>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="document_load()">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr><td align="center">
        <input type="button" onClick="dec_click()"
               value="より透明に">
        <input type="button" onClick="inc_click()"
               value="より不透明に">
    </th></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><p id="label">Opacity=100</td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center" style="
        background-image:url(back00.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
    ">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff" id="fore">
    </th></tr></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[filterプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx)はInternet Explorer 4.0で導入されたものですが、Internet Explorer 9から非推奨、Internet Explorer 10から削除されています。
記述されているHTMLが想定している環境では正しく動作します。

Comment: 一応[こちら](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/filter)も無くは無いですが、構文的にsayuriさんのリンクした方なんですよね...